# Flight booking system

Tags: vb.net, function, module, vb.net-2010

I have created a simply flight booking system. When the user selects the calculate button, it will calculate the price for the number of adults and children selected from the combobox option. The calculations are created inside the try catch and the if statements depending on the selection in combo box 1 and combo box 2. I need to create a module and put the calculate function inside the module, call the function in the calculate button. The price of the flight is dependent on the destination selected.

This is the source code for the program
Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btncalculateprice_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncalculateprice.Click
        Dim PricechildrenLocal As Integer = 1200
        Dim PriceadultsLocal As Integer = 12000
        Dim totalAdults As Integer
        Dim totalChildren As Integer
        Dim totalPrice As Integer
        Dim totalPrice1 As Integer
        Dim totalPrice2 As Integer


        Try

            If cmbadults.Text = 0 Then
                totalAdults += 0
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 1 Then
                totalAdults += 1
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 2 Then
                totalAdults += 2
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 3 Then
                totalAdults += 3
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 4 Then
                totalAdults += 4
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 5 Then
                totalAdults += 5
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 6 Then
                totalAdults += 6
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 7 Then
                totalAdults += 7
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 8 Then
                totalAdults += 8
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 9 Then
                totalAdults += 9
            End If
            If cmbadults.Text = 10 Then
                totalAdults += 10
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try



        Try

            If cmbchildren.Text = 0 Then
                totalChildren += 0
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 1 Then
                totalChildren += 1
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 2 Then
                totalChildren += 2
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 3 Then
                totalChildren += 3
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 4 Then
                totalChildren += 4
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 5 Then
                totalChildren += 5
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 6 Then
                totalChildren += 6
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 7 Then
                totalChildren += 7
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 8 Then
                totalChildren += 8
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 9 Then
                totalChildren += 9
            End If
            If cmbchildren.Text = 10 Then
                totalChildren += 10
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        Try

            If ComboBox1.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 100
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 150
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 100
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 150
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal - 1000
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal - 2000
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal - 500
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal - 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal

            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" And ComboBox2.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" And ComboBox2.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 100
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 150
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200



            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 100
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 150
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200


            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 100
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 150
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200


            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal - 500
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal - 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB) (CPT)" And ComboBox2.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal - 500
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal - 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Lanseria Airport (JHB)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200

            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal - 500
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal - 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" And ComboBox2.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" And ComboBox2.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal - 500
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal - 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200

            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Bloemfontien Airport (BFN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal - 500
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal - 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Cape Town International (CPT)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" And ComboBox2.Text = "King Shaka International Airport (DBN)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" And ComboBox2.Text = "O.R Tambo International Airport (JHB)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal - 500
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal - 1000
            ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Port Elizabeth Airport (PE)" And ComboBox2.Text = "Polokwane International Airport (PLK)" Then
                totalPrice1 = totalChildren * PricechildrenLocal + 150
                totalPrice2 = totalAdults * PriceadultsLocal + 200

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        totalPrice = totalPrice1 + totalPrice2
        Price.Text = Format(totalPrice, "currency")
        Adults.Text = totalAdults
        Children.Text = totalChildren 

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnbookflight_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnbookflight.Click
        Dim form As New Confirm
        If cmbadults.SelectedItem = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select the number of adults")
        Else
            If cmbchildren.SelectedItem = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please select the number of children")
            Else
        
                If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select the depature destination")
                Else
                    If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "" Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Please select the going to destination")
                    Else
                        Confirm.Show()
                    End If
                End If
                End If
            End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmbadults_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbadults.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub rbnoneway_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbnoneway.CheckedChanged
        If rbnoneway.Checked Then
            lblreturndate.Hide()
        Else
            lblreturndate.Show()
        End If
        If rbnoneway.Checked Then
            dtereturn.Hide()
        Else
            dtereturn.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        cmbtitle.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        cmbadults.Text = ""
        cmbchildren.Text = ""
        ComboBox1.Text = ""
        ComboBox2.Text = ""
        dtedepature.Text = ""
        dtereturn.Text = ""
        rbnoneway.Checked = False
        rbnroundtrip.Checked = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you should think what kind of objects you are having, and putting them into classes.

For a flight booking system I can think of a few classes;

Passanger,Airport,Flight,FlightCompany

And work out each of these classes like;

```
public class Passanger
    public name as string
    public passportnumber as string
end class
```

And this is sooo, well oefff;

```
Try

    If cmbadults.Text = 0 Then
        totalAdults += 0
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 1 Then
        totalAdults += 1
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 2 Then
        totalAdults += 2
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 3 Then
        totalAdults += 3
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 4 Then
        totalAdults += 4
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 5 Then
        totalAdults += 5
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 6 Then
        totalAdults += 6
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 7 Then
        totalAdults += 7
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 8 Then
        totalAdults += 8
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 9 Then
        totalAdults += 9
    End If
    If cmbadults.Text = 10 Then
        totalAdults += 10
    End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

you could better; 
    totalAdults += val(cmbadults.txt)

Answer (score 0):

public class Passanger
public name as TAREQ
public passportnumber as SKAIK
end class If ComboBox1.Text = "Istanbul Airport (IST)" And ComboBox2.Text = "JAKARTA Town International (CGK)" Then